# jEdit Java - Compare Class path syntax from Eclipse and how to impliment

Tags: java, swing, jedit

This should be simple, I am learning java and want to use jEdit because its light weight on my  linux box. In Eclipse I have the option to add external libraries under the build path with all point and click. So in Eclipse my path to the jars are /opt/andev/lib. Where does this syntax go when you port to jEdit? I have searched but i dont thimk I am phrasng my question properly so I provided the comparison function from eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, jEdit is not a Java IDE, but only a text editor. How do you plan to compile your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`org.gjt.sp.jedit.textarea.StandaloneTextArea`](http://www.jedit.org/api/org/gjt/sp/jedit/textarea/StandaloneTextArea.html) "to embed a `jEdit` `TextArea` into other applications." The API includes an example. You'll need to look at `jedit.props` "for properties that can be set."

Addendum: Oops, I misunderstood the question. You might look at a Java-centric [plugin](http://plugins.jedit.org/list.php?category=5) like `Classpath` that "Maintains global and project-specific java classpaths."